# Outlook rest-api from powershell returning oath request (401)

Tags: azure, powershell, oauth-2.0, outlook, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to create an auto notification app from outlook,
which I tried to use outlook rest API to do that.

for now I'm just making a simple code, but the result always returning error code 401

I've tried to register my apps into app registration on my Azure tenants. but have no luck nor I understand what to do next...

```
$uri = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/sendmail"

$userName = << my username >>
$password = << my password >>

$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName,$password

$body = "{
 ""Subject"":""rest API test"",
 ""Importance"":""High"",
 ""Body"":{
 ""ContentType"":""HTML"",
 ""Content"":""test test 1 2 3""
 },
 ""ToRecipients"":[{
 ""Address"":""<< my recipients >>""
 }]
 }"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Credential $credb -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body
```

the result from api said :

```
{"error":{"code":"OAuthMissingForThisApiVersion","message":"Authentication for this API version requires OAuth."}}
```

which is why I tried to register my app to azure app registration to get my token.

do anyone knows how to solve this problem?
or even some tutorial to show me how to set an app registration until I can get the token to my powershell app.

regards,

Comment: You are creating `$cred`, but use `$credb`. Is that just a typo?. Also, it looks like you are setting up the credentials using a plaintext password, or is `<< my password >>` already a SecureString?

Comment: Did you assign permission for this API on azure portal?

Comment: @Theo Excuse me, yes it was a typo, and just like you said my password are already a SecureString

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron , I followed this tutorial:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/10/30/how-to-create-a-native-powershell-app-registration-to-connect-to-azure-sql-db/
registered my app and also set up the allowed API but still don’t have any luck to connect this to my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://outlook.office.com/api/v1.0 doesn't support Basic auth as OAuth is the recommended auth mechanism, but you can continue to use https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0 if you need to keep using Basic auth.

Try something like below, it should work

```
$uri = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail"


$UserName = "mv.v@my.domain"
$Password = cat C:\MydomainCreds.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username,$password


$body = "{
""Message"":{
 ""Subject"": ""This is a send test"",
 ""Importance"": ""High"",
 ""Body"": {
 ""ContentType"": ""HTML"",
 ""Content"": ""How about this for a surprise!""
 },
 ""ToRecipients"": [
 {
 ""EmailAddress"":{
  ""Address"": ""mytestmailbox@anywhere.com""
  }
 }
 ]
 }}"  

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Credential $cred -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
```

Hope it helps.